# How to setup sql database in windows?

Tags: c#, sql, database, windows, visual-studio

I've been trying to create SQL database in my Visual Studio with C#.

But it keeps saying that SQL database is not set up or it is not installed on my PC.

Then I went to check whether it is installed and after checked it is already installed. So my question is how to set SQL database on my windows PC?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) normally comes with SQL Server.  Try opening up SSQS.  There is a login window with instance name of Server.  Use same instance name in your C# application that is in the login window.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? SQL is just the *query language* - used by many database systems. Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.